# How do I stop getting updates for Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool and Windows Defender?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, windows-defender

I have disabled the service for Windows Defender and I have configured the Action Center to not monitor or notify me about Spyware and Unwanted software protection. Windows Updates however really wants to me to constantly download updates to these programs. I unselect the checkbox to not install the updates and I also right click and specify "Hide Update" but the updates keep coming back.

How do I tell Windows Updates I never want these updates?

Answer (score 5):

Disabling Windows Update for Malicious Software Removal Tool:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MRT]
"DontOfferThroughWUAU"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: This won't prevent the current version from running. See http://serverfault.com/q/759338/33095

Comment: Great find for that key, this answer should have much more votes.

Answer (score 2):

If Windows Defender really bothers you, see this article:
[How To Disable, Uninstall or Remove Windows Defender in Vista](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2008/02/14/how-to-disable-uninstall-or-remove-windows-defender-in-vista/).
Uninstalling it will certainly get rid of the updates.

Regarding Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool, I don't believe you can stop them, since each is a separate and new update. However, this doesn't install any software on your computer, just runs the latest antivirus scan from Microsoft for not-too-many viruses. It completes rather quickly and is a positive protection for your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding WMSRT, I stole this from http://forums.speedguide.net/showthread.php?165854-Microsoft-Windows-Malicious-Software-Removal-Tool! and it worked for me.

• Q27: How do I prevent this tool from being offered to me by using Windows Update or Automatic Updates?

A27: When you are first offered the Malicious Software Removal Tool through Windows Update or Automatic Updates, you can choose to decline downloading and running the tool by declining the EULA. This decline can apply to just the current version of the tool or to both the current version of the tool and any future versions, depending on the options you choose. If you have already accepted the EULA and if you would prefer not to install the tool through Windows Update, click to clear the check box that corresponds to the tool in the Windows Update UI.

Comment: Declining the EULA is the way to go. Useless tool.