# Win 7, permanent update of “Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool”

Tags: windows-7, security, windows-update

I get permanent update offers for “Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool” and installed them with success, but with the next restart I get another offer of the same version again.

I have tried to manually install the tool, also went OK, but again does not stop new offers of the very same version. From " [How do I stop getting updates for Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool and Windows Defender?](https://superuser.com/questions/98313/how-do-i-stop-getting-updates-for-windows-malicious-software-removal-tool-and-wi) " I can derive it is possible to stop the updates (for the tool) entirely.

But I wonder how I can install the tool that it is recognized and no more updates for the same version are offered?

[image: Win 7 update history]

Comment: Try running disk-cleanup and checking "Windows Update Cleanup"

Comment: Tested, unfortunately the issue persist. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I had this with another update on XP. I never got to the bottom of it, but told the system to ignore the update. The problem was eventually resolved when I reinstalled (for other reasons), but that's not worth doing for just this. You could try hiding it, then allowing it again after the next update cycle. The next version may be better behaved, but it is no great loss if you need to leave it hidden, as your anti-virus almost certainly offers better protection than MRT.